# For how long a node keep its key?

Tags: security, key

just a simple question:

- for how long every server of the net keep its private ? Or when every server change the key ?

I ask this because if a hacker steal the keys of the entire network how long he can use the key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is considered valid for a timeframe like a month - that's my observation as a node operator I used to be some years ago. You can regenerate keys anytime just by cleaning the key folder and restarting Tor.